# Access a child "current" object in rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I want to get the object the child node is referering to, so I can make a query.

My code looks like this:

```
child @course_types => :course_types do |course_type|
  attributes :id, :name, :deleted
  child CourseTypeCategory.where(course_type: course_type, active: true) => :category_position do
    attributes :category_id, :position
  end
end
```

The result of this query `CourseTypeCategory.where(course_type: course_type, active: true)` is always returning the same result as if `course_type` was always the same each type it is rendered (in this case I suspect is always the first object of @course_types). Is there a way to get the "current object" of the child and make a query like if you were doing a loop (like an `each do`)?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
child @course_types => :course_type do
    attributes :id, :name, :deleted
    node(:course_type_category) do |course_type|
        CourseTypeCategory.where(course_type: course_type, active: true).collect do |category|
            {category_id: category.id, position: category.position }
        end
    end
end
```

Sorry for so little information on this, I'm kind in a hurry.